Где лучше хранить статистические вопросы?
Всем привет. Разрабатываю телеграм-бота для отзывов на русском и английском языке.
В общем суть следующая: когда пользователь заходит в бот, то ему предлагают выбрать язык(русский, английский). В зависимости от выбранного языка, ему будут заданы вопросы на выбранном языке. И так мне интересно как лучше всего хранить эти самые вопросы: создать отдельный файлик, где объявить массив с двумя объектами вопросов на разных языках  или создать таблицу отдельную в базе данных под вопросы и обращаться к БД каждый раз, когда бот будет задавать вопросы пользователю.

У БД однозначно больше возможностей чем у файла...

БД без каких либо оправданий. Файлик для разработки подойдет, а потом на БД переключаться

@ksa а нужны ли эти возможности?

@andreymal, ты не у того спрашиваешь... :)

В вашем случае все упирается не в вопросы, а в ответы.
Т.е. нужно понимать что вы собираетесь делать с ответами пользователей. Если вы будете их как-то обрабатывать тут же в боте и выдавать сразу какой-то ответ, то в этом случае можно хранить вопросы и в файле. Это и проще и ресурсы на базу не нужны. И можно вопросы хранить даже не в файле, а в исходном коде програмы. Если же ответы пользователей надо сохранять для последующей обработки, то в этом случае уже удобнее база. Если ответы будут в базе, то и вопросы логично в эту же самую базу поместить.
Вторым по важности вопросом может служить тот момент, насколько часто вам надо будет изменять эти вопросы. Если ожидается, что вопросы будут меняться довольно часто (раз в неделю или т.п.) то имеет смысл хранить в базе. Так как внести изменения в базу может оказаться проще, чем вносить изменения в код бота и потом его деплоить на сервер.
Но в любом случае решение надо принимать вам исходя из тех функций, которые будет выполнять ваш бот и исходя из той нагрузки с которой он будет работать.
А в вашем вопросе недостаточно деталей для того чтобы дать четкий и объективный ответ. Ну и всегда может быть холивар между адептами баз данных и  теми кто считает что не нужно плодить сущности без необходимости.
